# How to split the label and text of a caption

Tags: captions

I can not figure out how to split the label and the text of a caption, just like this:

[image]

Comment: Which document class do you use? Are you currently loading the `caption` package?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: \begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
 \label{table:1}
  \caption{Average daily maximum hourly radiation and its average environmental temperature for each evaluated month.}  
 \begin{tabular}{ccc}
 \hline
  Month & Radiation [\(W/m^2\)] & Temperature [$^{\circ}$C] \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline
January & 791 & 31.6 \\
April & 686 & 30.5 \\
July & 636 & 26.6 \\
October & 855 & 30.7 \\
[1ex] 
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

Comment: What do you mean by "split the label and the caption"? Do you want a bigger gap/space between them? And what about the space between the caption and the table?

Comment: The label appeare like this: 
Table 2: Power generation comparison to Petrolina, 2013 data, with a transmittance of 95%.
And I need to apeare like this: 
Table 2 
Power generation comparison to Petrolina, 2013 data, with a transmittance of 95%.

Comment: your last comment wasn't very enlightening.  do you mean that "Table 2" should be alone on one line, with the text beginning on a separate line?

Comment: exactly, and without the colon

Comment: @RaphaelBHeideier You can (and please do) edit the question to add these lines of code directly.  Code is always more visible in the question itself than hidden among comments and code (especially [minimal working examples (MWEs)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)) always aid in understanding what is desired from a question.

Answer (score 5):

You should load the `caption` package with the options `labelsep=newline` and `singlelinecheck=false`.

In addition, if you want the caption to occupy the same width as the associated `tabular` material does, you should encase both the caption and the tabular material in a `threeparttable` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn,caption,threeparttable}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\captionsetup{labelsep=newline,
              singlelinecheck=false,
              skip=0.25\baselineskip}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{BBCM coefficients for vertical sensors in the four cardinal orientations.}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{4}{d{2.4}}}
\toprule
Coeff. & \mc{North} & \mc{South} & \mc{East} & \mc{West} \\
\midrule
$a_1$ &  1.1097 &  0.9141 &  1.1065 &  1.0670 \\
$\vdots$ \\
$c_2$ & -0.2464 &  0.2997 & -0.0947 &  0.5877 \\
$\vdots$ \\
$b_4$ &  0.0400 & -0.0299 &  0.0442 &  0.0853 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp] 
\centering  
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Average daily maximum hourly radiation and its average environmental temperature for each evaluated month.}\label{table:1} 
\begin{tabular}{lcc} 
\toprule 
Month & Radiation [W/m$^2$] & Temperature [$^{\circ}$C]  \\
\midrule
January & 791 & 31.6 \\ 
April & 686 & 30.5 \\ 
July & 636 & 26.6 \\ 
October & 855 & 30.7 \\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```